# mysql: get row index for an individual result for total rows with a given category

Tags: mysql

I'm really not sure how I should have worded the title, but here is what I'm needing:

I have a function that pulls one particular row from a table by ID.  That row contains a category ID as well, and an "order by" number and "order by suffix" alpha-numeric field.  (So it could be ordered as 1, 2, 2a, 2b, 3, 4, etc.)

What I need is to pull the row, then find out which row number it would be if I pulled all of the rows for the category that it is in and ordered it by the order number and order suffix.

So, if I had:

`Select ID, Category, Order, Suffix From table Where ID = 28;`

`ID: 28, Category: 4, Order: 2, Suffix: b`

Going off my previous example of entries in the same category with an order of `1, 2, 2a, 2b, 3, 4`, I would need to know that this particular item is the 4th item in that category.

Of course, I know I could just do a second query to pull all rows for that category and order them correctly, then loop through them and find out which one matches my item, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

**All example data and fields are just that: examples.  I already know my example field names are bad, etc.  ;)

**Edit**

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348d8/7/0

I had to use one query to get the results I needed and ended up using:

```
Select items.*, @category_id := items.category_id, 
  (Select t1.rank From 
     (Select t.item_id, @rank:=if(@rank, @rank+1, 1) AS rank
        From items As t
        Where @category_id = t.category_id
        Order By t.order_num Asc, t.order_suffix Asc) As t1
   Where items.item_id = t1.item_id) As rowNum
From items
Where items.item_id = 7;
```

Comment: Don't you already know it's the fourth category because you have `category: 4`? Or is that something else? I'm having a hard time visualizing your schema here, can you add sample data or build an SQLFiddle?

Comment: @McAdam331 No, the category ID is 4.  And in this example, there are 6 rows that are in category 4.

Yeah, I'll try to add some examples.

Comment: Okay, I think that makes more sense. I will try to update for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started by writing a simple query that selected each order number and ordered it in ascending order, along with a variable which adds the row number for us:

```
SET @rowNum := 0;

SELECT (@rowNum := @rowNum + 1) AS rowNum, CONCAT(orderNum, suffix) AS orderNum
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CONCAT(orderNum, suffix);
```

Then, you can use this as a subquery to get the row num for the one you need:

```
SET @rowNum := 0;

SELECT rowNum
FROM(
  SELECT (@rowNum := @rowNum + 1) AS rowNum, id
  FROM myTable
  ORDER BY CONCAT(orderNum, suffix)) tmp
WHERE id = 28;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b319ec/2) example that returns the expected result of 4.

EDIT:

Since you can have multiple categories, we need to update our subquery to only run on the necessary category. Unfortunately, we cannot reference the outer query inside of our subquery, so we need to add another simple one to grab the category_id like this:

```
SET @rowNum := 0;
SET @searchID := 7;

SELECT rowNum
FROM(
  SELECT (@rowNum := @rowNum + 1) AS rowNum, item_id
  FROM items
  WHERE category_id = (SELECT category_id FROM items WHERE item_id = @searchID)
  ORDER BY CONCAT(orderNum, suffix)) tmp
WHERE item_id = @searchID;
```

Note that instead of writing 7 twice and having to change the param each time I added another variable.

Here is the updated [Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348d8/15).

Comment: You work faster than I do.  Took me a minute to figure out where SQL Fiddle wanted the data.  haha~  I'll try this real quick and let you know.  Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: This is close, but when there are different categories, I'm not sure it will work.

Can you check out my fiddle and see where it's at right now?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348d8/7/0

I'm getting back a row count of 3, even though it should be 4.

Comment: James, good point. It will need to be updated to make sure the subquery is only run on the right category, I will update in a second.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.  I wasn't able to use quite this, but it helped me find the answer I needed.  I'll post it in case you are curious.